# problems with sdk manager

Tags: android, sdk, development-environment

I am facing problems while opening the sdk manager.It shows me the following line:
[2014-10-09 19:26:39 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] This version of F:\therap\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace your \ADT\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe with an older find_java.exe. I have uploaded older version [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70HSeNwd5LzdDFDb2Y0WnVMd2c/view). Just replace this.

Hope it works for you. It worked for mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the same issue. The SDK Manager is now opening without any issue at my end.

> Solution 1 (working fine): Download the find_java.exe file from
>   previous (working) SDK. Link: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9im85Cl0QPaV3ZkeWI0dkRVNnc/view?usp=sharing) Paste & replace the file you downloaded to %ProgramFiles%\\tools\lib\
>
> Solution 2: Download the previous SDK and replace it with current version.
>   Link: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe
>
> Solution 3: In /tools/android.bat  set java_exe =
>   %ProgramFiles%\\bin\java.exe comment out REM call
>   lib\find_java.bat