# Cannot open Android-sdk manager in eclipse

Tags: java, android

'G:\ADT-BU~2\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2015-02-28 18:06:30 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
This is my sdk path that i have st.I cannot open android-sdk manager .I lost my hope to make it open again.Kindly help me...I spent two days for it to make open but still i cant

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279816/problems-with-sdk-manager. this guy have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and i have solved that:
Replace your \ADT\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe with an older find_java.exe. I have uploaded older version here. Just replace this.
Hope it works for you. It worked for mine....